# After updating to GAE 1.9.49 Maven fails to execute goal endpoints_get_discovery_doc

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, maven-gae-plugin

I tried to update the GAE version to the latest 1.9.49 released on Jan 30, 2017, and encountered the following issue:

```
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.49:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) @ dugout-api-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - get endpoints discovery doc...
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.AFDApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.AFLApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.AFSApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.ALApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.APApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.ARApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.AUApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.AUtApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.admin.BaseAdminApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.BaseApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.chat.ChatApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.BasePublicApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FDApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FDrApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FLApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FSApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FTApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.GCrApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.PApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.SApiService
[INFO] Using Class Name: com.project.api.resource.pub.UApiService
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-discovery-doc, -cp, D:\project\project-api\project-api-web\target\project-api-web-develop-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;D:\project\project-api\project-api-web\target/classes;D:\project\project-api\project-common\target\project-common-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\googlecode\objectify\objectify\5.1.8\objectify-5.1.8.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.3.1\gson-2.3.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.5.4\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.5.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.5.4\jackson-core-2.5.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.5.0\jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.5.4\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-service-email\target\project-service-email-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\mandrillapp\wrapper\lutung\lutung\0.0.5\lutung-0.0.5.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-io\commons-io\1.3.2\commons-io-1.3.2.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\sendgrid\sendgrid-java\2.2.2\sendgrid-java-2.2.2.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3.4\httpmime-4.3.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\json\json\20140107\json-20140107.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\sendgrid\smtpapi-java\1.2.0\smtpapi-java-1.2.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.4\httpclient-4.3.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\github\spullara\mustache\java\compiler\0.8.17\compiler-0.8.17.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\log4j\log4j\1.2.12\log4j-1.2.12.jar;D:\mvn_repo\logkit\logkit\1.0.1\logkit-1.0.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\avalon-framework\avalon-framework\4.1.3\avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-persistence\target\project-persistence-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-cache\target\project-cache-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.0\commons-collections4-4.0.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-service\target\project-service-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\gocardless\gocardless-java\3.1.0\gocardless-java-3.1.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.5.4\jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-service-channel\target\project-service-channel-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\pusher\pusher-rest-java\0.9.0\pusher-rest-java-0.9.0.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-api-opta\target\project-api-opta-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.8\xstream-1.4.8.jar;D:\mvn_repo\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\appengine\tools\appengine-gcs-client\0.6\appengine-gcs-client-0.6.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\apis\google-api-services-storage\v1-rev68-1.21.0\google-api-services-storage-v1-rev68-1.21.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\api-client\google-api-client\1.21.0\google-api-client-1.21.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client\1.21.0\google-oauth-client-1.21.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-appengine\1.22.0\google-api-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-appengine\1.22.0\google-oauth-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-servlet\1.22.0\google-oauth-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jdo\1.22.0\google-http-client-jdo-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-servlet\1.22.0\google-api-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\javax\jdo\jdo2-api\2.3-eb\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;D:\mvn_repo\javax\transaction\transaction-api\1.1\transaction-api-1.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-appengine\1.22.0\google-http-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\http-client\google-http-client\1.22.0\google-http-client-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson2\1.22.0\google-http-client-jackson2-1.22.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.1.4\woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar;D:\mvn_repo\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;D:\project\project-api\project-api-euros\target\project-api-euros-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-persist\4.0\guice-persist-4.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;D:\mvn_repo\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\appengine\appengine-remote-api\1.9.28\appengine-remote-api-1.9.28.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.49\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.49.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.49\appengine-endpoints-1.9.49.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\inject\guice\4.0\guice-4.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;D:\mvn_repo\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-servlet\4.0\guice-servlet-4.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;D:\mvn_repo\joda-time\joda-time\2.7\joda-time-2.7.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;D:\mvn_repo\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-labs\1.9.49\appengine-api-labs-1.9.49.jar;D:\mvn_repo\org\scribe\scribe\1.3.6\scribe-1.3.6.jar, -o, D:\project\project-api\project-api-web\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, D:\project\project-api\project-api-web\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -f, rest, com.project.api.resource.admin.AFDApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.AFLApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.AFSApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.ALApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.APApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.ARApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.AUApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.AUtApiService, com.project.api.resource.admin.BaseAdminApiService, com.project.api.resource.BaseApiService, com.project.api.resource.chat.ChatApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.BasePublicApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FDApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FDrApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FLApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FSApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.f.FTApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.GCrApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.PApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.SApiService, com.project.api.resource.pub.UApiService]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] project-api ......................................... SUCCESS [  4.547 s]
[INFO] project-common-test-dep ............................. SUCCESS [  0.430 s]
[INFO] project-common ...................................... SUCCESS [  7.699 s]
[INFO] project-cache ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.026 s]
[INFO] project-persistence ................................. SUCCESS [  3.256 s]
[INFO] project-common-test-utils ........................... SUCCESS [  0.727 s]
[INFO] project-service-email ............................... SUCCESS [  1.296 s]
[INFO] project-service-channel ............................. SUCCESS [  1.263 s]
[INFO] project-service ..................................... SUCCESS [  5.777 s]
[INFO] project-api-opta .................................... SUCCESS [  4.171 s]
[INFO] project-api-euros ................................... SUCCESS [  1.577 s]
[INFO] project-api-web ..................................... FAILURE [  3.696 s]
[INFO] project-api-import .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project-api-task .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] project-build-ear ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.682 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-01T20:09:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/485M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.49:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) on project project-api-web: -f -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.49:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) on project project-api-web: -f
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: -f
    at com.google.appengine.endpoints.EndpointsMojo.executeEndpointsCommand(EndpointsMojo.java:114)
    at com.google.appengine.endpoints.EndpointsGetDiscoveryDoc.execute(EndpointsGetDiscoveryDoc.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
```

For previous versions the build succeeded for the same goal.

Part of the relevant `project-api-web\pom.xml` is shown below:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <webXml>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints</directory>
                        <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                        <includes>
                            <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                            <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

It appears that after update `com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool` fails to handle the format option: `-f, rest`

So currently the update is reverted to version 1.9.48 as a workaround.

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are not alone! I am also facing the same error with no remedy yet!

Comment: I filled bug here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13564&thanks=13564&ts=1487410164

Answer (score 2):

Working on it. Fix will be in 1.9.50 release.

Answer (score 0):

I've [reported this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/81) to the GitHub tracker for the `appengine-maven-plugin`. It appears specific to this component as changing the version for the plugin specifically is what affects the bug. There is also [another issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/80) which was reported recently on that tracker regarding deployments which seems dependent on this one.